# screen compared to opening virtual consoles

Tags: gnu-screen, tty

When pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F7</kbd> to change virtual terminals, how is this different from using the linux command line tool screen to split a terminal session and open a new session with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, c?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of technical similarities and differences, but the one difference that should matter to you is that unlike the virtual consoles, using `screen`, you can attach to a `screen` session from *any* terminal connection to that computer:

- other virtual consoles
- terminal emulators running in X
- an `ssh` (or telnet) connection from another computer

All that is necessary for this ability to attach:

- you have permission (usually, running as the same user)
- the `screen` session is on the machine where you want to attach

Once you have attached to a `screen` session, that terminal acts (well, not *"just like"*) as if you were connected on the original terminal where you started `screen`.

You can do the same with `tmux`, of course, but their sessions are separate — just like virtual consoles.